# fabric.js assign event listener to an object for multiple events

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fabricjs

I am asking this mainly out of curiosity as it is possible to replicate code but being deep in rails at the minute, repetition makes me feel dirty and I can't find it in the docs.

Suppose I have a `rect = fabric.Rect` and I wanted to add a listener for say, moving and modified that do the same thing:

```
rect.on('moving', function() {
    console.log('moving or modified'); 
});

rect.on('modified', function() {
    console.log('moving or modified'); 
});
```

is it possible to combine these in some way?

I'm very new to JS and so this could be a simple thing in JS that I've not come across yet but again, it's not mentioned in Fabric docs that I've seen.

Comment: use only one why you want to combine?

Comment: because they're two distinct events that may need the same action being performed when they are triggered.

Comment: check the sequence of events after move there this modify trigger

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm a little late, but just in case anyone else has this problem - you just need to move your common code into a function, and then pass key/value pairs to the on() function:

```
function doLog() {
    console.log('moving or modified');
}

rect.on({
    'moving': doLog,
    'modified': doLog
});
```